# iPhone Launch Screen Only displaying name and copyright

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the launch image set up correctly as in it's correctly linked to the image.xcasset folder with the launch image (there are two, with correct dimensions). However, only the title of the app and the copyright gets shown during launch image (the default). How do you fix this?

Comment: Can you include a picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In xcode 6 you can search for LaunchScreen.xib in your bundle and set the UI for launch there only

Answer (score 0):

Need to change Lunch screen file to `Main.storyboard`

[image]